# While moving s3 files to cloudfront, want to exclude some files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have files stored in s3, some files are accessed often, but other files are just stored for later use.

We do not need to cdn these files at all.

Is there a way to tell cloudfront not to fetch these files from s3?

Comment: Considering that CloudFront is a pull-through CDN, and that there is no charge for objects stored in CloudFront, I can't help but wonder what your motivation is for asking the question.  Will you elaborate, please?  The subject line of the question is also confusing, since files never "move from" S3 to CloudFront.  CloudFront is a cache, with transient storage only.

Comment: i read somewhere (can't find in my chrome history..) that it costs to move files from s3 to cloudfront. So I thought cloudfront moves the files from s3 as soon as it sees them. I guess I'm wrong. Are you saying (by pull-through), unless user requests a file, it wont' be moved from s3 to cloudfront?

Comment: It won't be *copied* from S3 to CloudFront, correct.  Files never *move* from S3 to CloudFront.  Also, files are not "in" or "not in" CloudFront as a whole -- each edge location is independent, so a file will only be cached in the specific edge locations through which they are requested.  Previously, there were bandwidth charges when files were fetched from S3 by CloudFront, but there is no longer a charge for this bandwidth [as of December, 2014](http://https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-data-transfer-price-reduction/), so that *might* be what you're thinking of.

Comment: If these comments have addressed your question, I can write them up as a proper answer.  Does that cover what you were looking for?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: yes please

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to move them to a separate s3 bucket however another option is to keep the objects you don't want exposed as private.

> By default, your Amazon S3 bucket and all of the objects in it are private—only the AWS account that created the bucket has permission to read or write the objects in it. If you want to allow anyone to access the objects in your Amazon S3 bucket using CloudFront URLs, you must grant public read permissions to the objects. (This is one of the most common mistakes when working with CloudFront and Amazon S3. You must explicitly grant privileges to each object in an Amazon S3 bucket.)

Source:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html#GettingStartedUploadContent

Hopefully that answers your question.